# flutterfire configure & firebase-tools how to fix?

Tags: firebase-tools

THE PROBLEM
..........

```
PS C:\Users\ahsan\StudioProjects\dropshop> flutterfire configure --project=flutterapp-7dd66
⠴ Fetching available Firebase projects...
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
#
^

#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1250:9)
#2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:915:22)
#3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:35:10)
#4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:612:36)
#5      runFirebaseCommand (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase.dart:95:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      getProjects (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase.dart:114:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      ConfigCommand._selectFirebaseProject (package:flutterfire_cli/src/commands/config.dart:300:24)      
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      ConfigCommand.run (package:flutterfire_cli/src/commands/config.dart:390:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     main (file:///C:/Users/ahsan/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutterfire_cli-0.2.7/bin/flutterfire.dart:57:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

---

SOME DETAILS:
............

I installed node js and activated flutterfire using dart pub ... command,
then i logged into firebase! using firebase login.
after that, flutterfire configure [which produced error]
Fetching available Firebase projects...

''

```
`Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
#
^

#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1250:9)`
```

''....................................................................................

SOLUTION:

1. I CREATED BRAND NEW FLUTTER PROJECT AND REPAIRED PUB CACHE! USING : dart pub cache repair
2. I REDOWNLOADED and opened FIREBASE CLI INSTANT.EXE FILE. AND LOGGED INTO IT.
3. I redownloaded FIREBASE-TOOLS USING, npm install -g firebase-tools.
4. I CREATED THE FLUTTER PROJECT AND CREATED NEW FLUTTER APP THERE IN FIREBASE CONSOLE.
5. I TYPED  " flutterfire configure "  in  newly downloaded firebase-cli-instant window. and it successfully fetched the projects and i selected my created project and i selected the platform ios,android ...
   and it configured!!
6. you could also type flutterfire configure --project: ....

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

I CREATED BRAND NEW FLUTTER PROJECT AND REPAIRED PUB CACHE! USING : dart pub cache repair

I REDOWNLOADED and opened FIREBASE CLI INSTANT.EXE FILE. AND LOGGED INTO IT.

I redownloaded FIREBASE-TOOLS USING, npm install -g firebase-tools.

I CREATED THE FLUTTER PROJECT AND CREATED NEW FLUTTER APP THERE IN FIREBASE CONSOLE.

I TYPED " flutterfire configure " in newly downloaded firebase-cli-instant window. and it successfully fetched the projects and i selected my created project and i selected the platform ios,android ... and it configured!!

you could also type flutterfire configure --project: ....

Comment: Should write in proper casing.

Comment: sorry, i wanted people to focus on this answer as it was frustrating solving it ;(

Answer (score 0):

If you have 'fvm' then uninstall it or disable it.
`dart pub global deactivate fvm`
for mac or you also visit the site [https://fvm.app/docs/guides/faq/#:~:text=How%20to%20uninstall%20FVM%E2%80%8B,Delete%20that%20directory](https://fvm.app/docs/guides/faq/#:%7E:text=How%20to%20uninstall%20FVM%E2%80%8B,Delete%20that%20directory). to get exact solution of disabling the fvm.
Once disable, close the terminal and now try to do the same process again, `firebase configure`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this because I was also having same series errors as you are having.

1. sudo gem install xcodeproj (optional) (macOS only)
2. Delete google-services.json(android/app/google-services.json)
3. Delete firebase_app_id_file.json (ios/firebase_app_id_file.json) (macOS only)
4. flutterfire configure --project:
   or
   flutterfire configure

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution or a guide for others, it's great! Here's a breakdown of the steps : it woeked successfully:

0. first delete the pubspec.lock file in the project files,
1. **Create a new Flutter project:**

   - Use the command: `flutter create project_name`
2. **Repair Pub Cache:**

   - Execute the command: `dart pub cache repair`
3. **Download and open Firebase CLI instant.exe file:**

   - Ensure you have the Firebase CLI installed and updated.
4. **Log into Firebase CLI:**

   - Execute the command: `firebase login`
5. **Download Firebase Tools:**

   - Use the command: `npm install -g firebase-tools`
6. **Create Flutter app in Firebase Console:**

   - Go to the Firebase Console and create a new Flutter project.
7. **Configure FlutterFire:**

   - Run the command: `flutterfire configure`
   - Select your project and choose the platforms (iOS, Android, etc.).
8. **Optional: Specify project in configure command:**

   - You can also use: `flutterfire configure --project:your_project_id` to specify the project directly.

These steps should help you set up Flutter with Firebase successfully. If you encounter any issues during this process, make sure to check for updates on FlutterFire and Firebase tools, and consult the documentation for any specific requirements or changes.